# Creating an inventory booking system on infopath with data connections

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

A brief overview - At work we have protective equipment that people need to book out from time to time on visits to construction sites.

My Task - Create a form where people can book out parts of this equipment.

Requirements -

1. There is a set amount of this equipment that we hold onsite, the form should be able to pick up this information (it is currently held in a sharepoint list)
2. When the form is filled out a query would stop submission if more items are requested than available.
3. Submit data back to the original form to amend the available value so when a new form is opened the available amount is less.

I have created one SharePoint list with a column for each piece/size of equipment - for example "Overalls White 42T" with a quantity that gets picked up by my infopath form.

My issue, how do i perform a submit that lowers the available amount by X, so that this new value is picked up in a new form,but when items are returned (a button is pressed?) this action can be reversed.